# How to use a function to greet a person in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, call

Hello so my question is about this assignment and how I am stuck on how to proceed with getting the persons name to be added to the greeting. The assignment directions are as follows:
 Create a function called greet that has one parameter called name and does not return a value. When greet is called, it should say hello to the value passed in as the argument to name. For instance, greet("Bob"); should print out Hello, Bob!

Create a function to greet a person and return their name.

```
var greet_name = function(person_name, greet) {
  var text = greet + ',' + name;
  var person_name = text
  text = "Enter your name here";
  person_name = prompt(text); stop 

  console.log(text);
  var greet = greet_name(person_name, greet);
};
greet_name()
```

Some advice on what the next steps would be great or just suggestions on places to edit the code.

Thanks

Comment: Did you encounter some problem? "Some advice would be great" isn't a valid question.

Answer (score 3):

```js
function greet(name) {
  console.log("Hello, " + name + "!");
}

greet("Bob");
```

Comment: Usually wouldn't upvote a 100% code dump. But honestly there's nothing more to say here. Solution is simple, earlier approach makes no sense, what more is there to say

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so we only need one parameter for the function:
`function greet(name){`
And We know that we don't need to have the function return anything, but it needs to print out the name: `console.log("Hello, " + name);` Additionally, we want a prompt so the user can enter a name of their choice. We can actually do this during the function call: `greet(prompt("Enter Name:"))` Thus, we have a fully functional greeter. Final product:
    `function greet(name){
    console.log("Hello, "+ name);
    }
     greet(prompt("Enter Name:"));`

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
var greet_name = function(person_name, greet) {
    console.log(greet + " " + person_name);
};
greet_name(prompt("Enter Your Name : ","Enter Name"),"Welcome");
```

Answer (score 0):

This Might be an easier and cleaner way to do it.

```
var greeting = (userName)=>{
    var userName = prompt("Enter Name");
    alert("Hello " + userName + "!" );
}
greeting();
```